# Sublime Text: escape multiple selections to last selection region instead of first

Tags: sublime-text

In Sublime Text (using Sublime Text 3), you can get out of a multiple selection / multiple caret mode by pressing the Esc key.  When you do this, only the first selection / caret will remain.

Is there a way to make it so that only the *last* selection / caret will remain instead?

I often find myself hitting escape then needing to move my cursor to what used to be the last selection.

Use case:

I type this using multiple selection:

```
int foo(
  int x,
  int x,
  int x,
  int x,
)
```

and I want to get rid of the last comma to get to:

```
int foo(
  int x,
  int x,
  int x,
  int x
)
```

I'd like to hit the Esc key and have my caret be right after that last `int x,`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think this is not a default command in sublime text. However you can easily create this behavior on your own.
Just press `Tools >> New Plugin...` and paste the following:

```py
import sublime_plugin


class SingleLastSelectionCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        view = self.view
        if len(view.sel()):
            last = view.sel()[-1]
            view.sel().clear()
            view.sel().add(last)
```

Afterwards create a keybinding:

```js
{ "keys": ["escape"], "command": "single_last_selection", "context":
    [
        { "key": "num_selections", "operator": "not_equal", "operand": 1 }
    ]
},
```

It might be necessary to copy all escape keybinding from the default keymap to keep the action precedence (hide autocompletion before removing multiple cursors and so on).

Comment: Super cool! I've been wanting this for ages never bothered to really search for it. I use `shift+escape` to still keep the other `escape` functionality.

Comment: This Fails when the multiple selection is from DOWN -> UP ---

**Example:**

Say the first occurrence is on _line 204_ and the second occurrence of same  word/phrase is say on _line 52_, now when you first select the word/phrase on _line 204_ (1st selection) and then hit `Ctrl+D`  word/phrase on _line 52_ is selected (2nd selection) but now when you hit `Shift + Esc`, the cursor jumps back to first selection _line 204_ and does not remain on the last selection _line 52_ (last selection)
---
**Is it possible to modify the script to solve this ???**

Comment: @bTech I guess they are sorted by appearance, but you can work around this by pressing esc when you reach the top of the file and continue.